# Rafaelfc/pear in Puppet with Hiera

Tags: puppet, pear, hiera

I need to install FirePHPCore with PEAR in Puppet infrastructure.

Docs give an example

```
include pear
# If no version number is supplied, the latest stable release will be
# installed. In this case, upgrade PEAR to 1.9.2+ so it can use
# pear.drush.org without complaint.
pear::package { "PEAR": }
pear::package { "Console_Table": }

# Version numbers are supported.
pear::package { "drush":
  version => "4.5.0",
  repository => "pear.drush.org",
}
```

I implement it by this way

```
classes:
 - pear


pear::package:
 'PEAR':
pear::package:
 'Console_Table':


pear::package:
 'FirePHPCore':
  repository : 'pear.firephp.org'
```

But it doesn't work. I see errors on agent:

```
Error: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install {"FirePHPCore"=>{"repository"=>"pear.firephp.org"}}' returned 100: Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package {"FirePHPCore"=>{"repository"

Error: /Stage[main]/Pear/Package[{"FirePHPCore"=>{"repository"=>"pear.firephp.org"}}]/ensure: change from purged to present failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install {"FirePHPCore"=>{"repository"=>"pear.firephp.org"}}' returned 100: Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package {"FirePHPCore"=>{"repository"
```

Looks like it interpret `'FirePHPCore':` as `"FirePHPCore"=>`.

Can anyone understand what's wrong?

Comment: In Hiera file, can you change `repository :` to `'repository':` then try again?

Comment: changed to 'repository' but error was not changed. Looks like module is broken..

Comment: can you show me the pp file for package `FirePHPCore`? the error is in FirePHPCore puppet module. Normal the key `"FirePHPCore"` with => should not be followed by `{`

Comment: BMW, thank you for your help, I just wrote simple thing that works for me `  exec { "install FirePHP":
    command => "/usr/bin/pear channel-discover pear.firephp.org && /usr/bin/pear install firephp/FirePHPCore",
#    command => "/bin/date >> /home/tcadmin/date",
    onlyif => "/usr/bin/test  `/usr/bin/pear list -c firephp | grep -c Fire` -eq 0",
  }
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, looks like Rafaelfc/pear is broken, the simpliest way to install pear module via Puppet can be looks like this code:

```
exec { "install FirePHP":
    command => "/usr/bin/pear channel-discover pear.firephp.org && /usr/bin/pear install firephp/FirePHPCore",
    onlyif => "/usr/bin/test  `/usr/bin/pear list -c firephp | grep -c Fire` -eq 0",
  }
```